# Solving multiple equations through Loop in R

Tags: r, loops, equation

I have a list of non-linear equations and want to solve them simultaneously using loop. My goal is to find the parameters and r-square of each equation.

```
x<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
y<-c(0.12,0.15,0.19,0.29,0.52,0.60,0.66)
```

Here is the list of equations.

```
y~a*x+b
y~a*(x-b)
y~a+b*x+c*x^0.5
y~a*x/(b+x)
```

I can sove each equations individually and find its parameters, but I have more than 20 equations and  wonder if there is a way to solve all equations through loop or something.

```
fit1<-nls(y~a*x+b,start=list(a=1,b=1))
fit2<-nls(y~a*(x-b),start=list(a=1,b=1))
fit3<-nls(y~a+b*x+c*x^0.5,start=list(a=1,b=1,c=1)) 
fit4<-nls(y~a*x/(b+x),start=list(a=1,b=1))
```

#r square

```
Rsq_fit1<-cor(y,predict(fit1))^2
Rsq_fit2<-cor(y,predict(fit2))^2
Rsq_fit3<-cor(y,predict(fit3))^2
Rsq_fit4<-cor(y,predict(fit4))^2
```

#Coefficients and R-square

```
list(coef(fit1),coef(fit2),coef(fit3),coef(fit4))
list(Rsq_fit1,Rsq_fit2,Rsq_fit3,Rsq_fit4)
```

Comment: I added one more non-linear equation (y~a*exp((-(x-b)^2/(2*c^2))), but  I'm getting the following error message. Error in nls(x, df, start = setNames(as.list(rep(1, length(v))), v)) :
singular gradient

Answer (score 2):

If you put `x` and `y` in a dataframe and your equations in a list:

```r
df <- data.frame(x, y)

eq <- list(y~a*x+b,
           y~a*(x-b),
           y~a+b*x+c*x^0.5,
           y~a*x/(1+x))
```

Then you could do:

```r
do.call(rbind, lapply(eq, function(x) {
  v <- setdiff(all.vars(x), c("x", "y"))
  mod <- nls(x, df, start = setNames(as.list(rep(1, length(v))), v))
  rsq <- cor(df$y, predict(mod))^2
  EQ <- do.call("substitute", list(x, env = as.list(round(coef(mod), 3))))
  data.frame(equation = deparse(EQ), r_squared = rsq)
}))
#>                                 equation r_squared
#> 1                 y ~ 0.102 * x + -0.046 0.9397561
#> 2                y ~ 0.102 * (x - 0.449) 0.9397561
#> 3 y ~ 0.337 + 0.222 * x + -0.449 * x^0.5 0.9628876
#> 4                  y ~ 0.503 * x/(1 + x) 0.6932539
```

Note that your fourth equation does not converge, so I have altered it slightly for demonstration purposes.

If you would like your results output in a numeric format, and have the results output even when `nls` fails, you can do:

```r
p <- unique(unlist(sapply(eq, function(x) setdiff(all.vars(x), c("x", "y")))))

do.call(rbind, lapply(eq, function(x) {
  v <- setdiff(all.vars(x), c("x", "y"))
  coefdf <- do.call(data.frame, setNames(as.list(rep(NA, length(p))), p))
  mod <- tryCatch({
    nls(x, df, start = setNames(as.list(rep(1, length(v))), v))
  }, error = function(e) "error")
  if(class(mod) == "character") {
    return(cbind(
       data.frame(equation = deparse(x)), 
       converged = FALSE,
       coefdf,
       r_squared = NA))
  }
  coefdf[1, v] <- round(coef(mod), 3)
  cbind(equation = deparse(x), 
        converged = TRUE,
        coefdf,
        r_squared = cor(df$y, predict(mod))^2)
}))
#>                    equation converged     a      b      c r_squared
#> 1             y ~ a * x + b      TRUE 0.102 -0.046     NA 0.9397561
#> 2           y ~ a * (x - b)      TRUE 0.102  0.449     NA 0.9397561
#> 3 y ~ a + b * x + c * x^0.5      TRUE 0.337  0.222 -0.449 0.9628876
#> 4         y ~ a * x/(b + x)     FALSE    NA     NA     NA        NA
```

Comment: You beat me to posting :) Mine wasn't as clean as yours anyway. Did you also get an error on the fourth formula? (I see that you changed it).

Comment: @M-- yes, I got an error. I have included an updated version that handles errors in nls

Comment: I added one more non-linear equation (y~exp(a+b*x+c), but  I'm getting the following error message.                                                                                    
Error in nlsModel(formula, mf, start, wts, scaleOffset = scOff, nDcentral = nDcntr) :
singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates         Is this due to the starting value?

Comment: @user21242742 that equation simplifies to `y ~ exp(b * x + (a + c))`, and whatever value `(a + c)` takes, there are an infinite number of values that "a" and "c" could take. For example, if a + c was 2, then the values (a = 1, c = 1) would be a solution, but so would (a = 136.2, c = -134.2). In this scenario, nls cannot choose values for a and c, and throws an error. You will always get a single gradient error if you have multiple parameters that should be merged into one. In any case, my second version above quietly handles such errors, quietly returning `NA` instead of stopping with an error